# Up-to-date Ignite web console docker image

Tags: ignite

I'm wondering if there is a up-to-date docker image for the Ignite web console?
When I pull "docker pull apacheignite/web-console-standalone" I only get an outdated version that isn't compatible with current web agent.

Or is the Dockerfile available so I can build the image myself without starting from the ground?

Maybe there is even a Dockerfile that puts webagent and console in one?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dontequila.

apacheignite/web-console-standalone will be updated soon.

You can also build docker by yourself:

1. Checkout Apache Ignite master: Ignite Git: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/ignite
2. cd modules/web-console/docker/standalone/
3. ./build.sh (you may need sudo).

Comment: @dontequila Docker image updated: https://hub.docker.com/r/apacheignite/web-console-standalone/tags/

Comment: Built it myself following your instruction, works great. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed the dashboard is missing in the web console that I built myself. It only allows config creation and SQL queries but no dashboard with node overview, CPU load etc. Must this feature configured separately?

Comment: The dashboard is actually also not in your updated webconsole anymore. Has this been removed intentionally?

Comment: has the dashboard been removed from the console?

Comment: @DonTequila Dashboard is not a part of Apache Ignite Web Console. It is available only at https://console.gridgain.com/ or as GridGain on-premise software.